# cannot pass value to PHP file from URL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem I use an internal server when I pass a value through the URL and type a valid value showing me a message that he did not scroll see my code:

// pass value from this URL:

```
http://localhost/test/get.php?name=aa

    <?php
    // include Marei DB Class 
    include 'DB.php';
    // get content input and create json object to parse it
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $obj = json_decode($data);
    // create db instance to use marei db queris 
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    // set type of header response to application/json for respone 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if(!empty($_GET["name"])){

      print "{\"status\":0,\"message\":\"Username is Non !\"}" ;

    }else{

     print "{\"status\":0,\"message\":\"Username is Don !\"}" ;

    }
    ?>

// print these lines : 
{"status":0,"message":"Username is Non !"}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. `$_GET["name"]` is `aa`, which is not empty. So it prints the first message.

Comment: Are you sure you have your output messages is correct? Your if reads "if not empty", meaning it executed the top code block if it's present

Comment: Don't generate JSON with strings, you should always use `json_encode()`.

Comment: Your code is executing as it reads.. it is saying username is non because that's what you coded. $_GET['name'] is not empty.

Comment: Yes ,i'm sure , it has printed these lines : {"status":0,"message":"Username is Non !"}

Comment: you was meaned to resolve my problem i will put results inside json_encode()

Comment: Yes, but why can't we use JSON with strings But we can use json_encode()

Answer (score -5, accepted):

`empty` is enough.  Also you can use

```
if (!$_GET["name"]) {
   print json_encode(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Username is Non !']);
}
```

Comment: it's saied SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: `$_GET['name']`, not `$_GET('name')` for starters. Your code will produce a notice if the array key is missing.

Answer (score 3):

Change `if(!empty($_GET["name"])){`
to `if(empty($_GET["name"])){`

You did the mistake to use `!` operator.
PHP is understanding it as a `not`

And you're asking if the `$_GET` variable is **NOT** empty the result is `true` of course.

Please check http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify the method in which a file is being uploaded to your server?  Form input?

Assuming that a file is being uploaded...I can see 2 maybe 3 issues, all of which are not mutually exclusive, so it could be be all three issues working together to foil your coding plans...

ONE  Use $_FILES , not input

$name = $_FILES['file']['name']; <--- name of the file from its source
$path - $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; <--- path to the uploaded file

you have to move the uploaded file from your uploads folder... to its new home.

TWO  Request method should be POST not GET... Especially the request is created by a form.

THREE - check your php.ini file to make sure file uploads are enabled.